# RSpec - as_null_object?

Tags: ruby, rspec2

It's not clear to me what the purpose of [`as_null_object`](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Mocks/Methods/as_null_object) is and in what scenarios you would use it?  According to the documentation on Relish:

> Use the `as_null_object` method to ignore any messages that aren't
>   explicitly set as stubs or message expectations.

Not registering with me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a null object when you don't care about the object's behavior or interaction, and don't want to explicitly stub everything out that's needed. Calling any method with any arguments on a null object will not result in a `NoMethodError` or `ArgumentError`. See also the Wikipedia entry on the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object).

Answer (score 9):

[The RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) explains this. I recommend you to read it.

> ... as_null object tells the mocked object to only listen for the messages we tell it to
>   expect, and ignore any other messages.

So, suppose one of your examples has the following code:

```
...
my_object = mock("my_object" ).as_null_object
other_thing = OtherThing.new(my_object)
my_object.should_receive(:some_method).with("string parameter value")
...
```

If the initialization code for OtherThing sends other messages (executes other methods) to my_object that are not "some_method", this example will not listen to them, isolating the test to what you actually want to test here.